# How to link multi html page in web pack?

Tags: webpack, href

I cant link another html page  with href=,  error message Cannot GET, is there something i have to do in webpack? same links and path work when not use webpack.  put on github

https://github.com/GGillies-Productions/Portfolio.git

f you want a look, hope that works!  Thanks